# django urls.py - project and application specific

Tags: python, django

How can I configure Django url resolution to have all other URLs other than `somedomain.com/admin` point to the application without any sort of prefix?

In my project's urls.py, I have

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include("photoapp.urls", namespace="photoapp")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and in `photoapp/urls.py`, I have

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index),
    url(r'^fileUpload/?$', views.file_upload)
)
```

Now, both these URLs have associated views within `photoapp/views.py`.  `somedomain.com` loads the template specified by `views.index`, but `somedomain.com/fileUpload` returns a 404.  Specifically, the error message states

```
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL
patterns, in this order:
    ^$
    ^admin/
```

My goal is to have

```
somedomain.com/admin
```

resolve to the admin app, and

```
somedomain.com
somedomain.com/fileUpload
somedomain.com/search?q=query
```

be handled by `photoapp/urls.py`.  How can I configure the app urls.py to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$` sign from the first url:

```
url(r'^', include("photoapp.urls", namespace="photoapp")),
```